# Generate a business key

Tags: nhibernate

What is the best way to generate a unique number for a business key?

In the example below, our customer wants a number (OrderNumber) they can use to refer to an Order.

```
<class name="Order">
  <id name="Id" ... />

  <property name="OrderNumber" column="order_number" />

</class>
```

Comment: What's your Id generator? Why don't you use that as Id? Are there any requirements on the OrderNumber (like sequential etc.?)

Comment: Whats your requirement on OrderNumber, Can it be any number or string and number or etc?

Comment: OrderNumber must be a sequential number. Holes are ok.
The Id is a Guid assigned by the application. We don't want to use a business identifier (OrderNumber) as a primary key.
Is is possible to use a nHibernate generator on a regular property?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found that the best way to perform these tasks is to write them in code and not leak them into the data layer. I don't let NHibernate calculate it.  I treat this concept as a fully fledged feature of the application.  This is nice because I can write tests for it and have flexibility.  Sometimes there are other factors involved in calculating the next sequence number, like a relationship to another entity.  Maybe you want sequential order numbers within the realm of a client: 02-001, 02-002 for client 02 and 01-001, 01-002 for client 01.

So I promote the concept of a SequneceNumber to a domain model object, map it with NHibernate and do the logic on my side.  Whenever I need a new one, I use an interface that looks something like

```
public interface ISequenceRepository
{
    string GetNextSequenceNumber(Customer customer);
}
```

And it manages the current sequence number in one record (per Customer) in a database table.  Whenever I call this function it increments the place-keeper in the database and returns the value.

A factory depends on this interface and uses it to build up the objects that need a sequence number.

Comment: This is an *ancient* answer of yours, I know. But I like the idea alot! Do you think you could share your SequenceNumber object, the mapping for it? Also, how you apply the number (ie, 003) transactionally within the save of a Client (ie,02)... Cheers

Comment: @Berryl - I don't have anything ready to go but imagine the simplest possible data row - a FK and an int.  The model would look like that, an entity reference and an int. the mapping would be straight.  As for the business rule for numbering and etc.. that would be totally unique to the situation.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the quick response. It helps, but this one just seems like one of those I need to work thru to really get it. Would make an awesome blog post on a topic I sure haven't seen addressed from a domain perspective! Cheers