# nhibernate alternate id's using generated properties

Tags: nhibernate, identity, sequences

** This question has been edited to make it simpler and more focused **

Employee has an EmployeeNumberValue property which I would like to have auto-incremented by the db. To the business domain, this is a unique id assigned to employees and used to identify them on employee cards, etc. To the database however, it is an alternate id and not the primary key.

NHib has a documented ability called [Generated Properties](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-generated). 
Per the docs, "generated properties are properties which have their values generated by the database. Typically, NHibernate applications needed to Refresh objects which contain any properties for which the database was generating values. Marking properties as generated, however, lets the application delegate this responsibility to NHibernate. Essentially, whenever NHibernate issues an SQL INSERT or UPDATE for an entity which has defined generated properties, it immediately issues a select afterwards to retrieve the generated values."

The problem I am having is that while NHib is making the additional SELECT to update the EmployeeNumberValue, it is not assigning the retrieved value to the property.

Can anyone see why this is happening what the fix is?

Cheers,
Berryl

FAILING TEST AND OUTPUT (tested w/ SQLite in memory db):

```
    [Test]
    public void Employee_OnInsert_EmployeeNumberValueIsIncremented() {

        var emp1 = new Employee
        {
            FullName = _fullName,
            Department = _department,
        };
        var emp2 = new Employee
        {
            FullName = _fullName,
            Department = _department,
        };

        var session = _SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(); 

        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.Save(_department);
            session.Save(emp1);
            session.Save(emp2);
            tx.Commit();
        }
        Assert.That(emp1.EmployeeNumberValue, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(emp2.EmployeeNumberValue, Is.EqualTo(2));
    }

NHibernate: INSERT INTO Employees (FirstName, LastName, DepartmentId, EmployeeId) 
        VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);@p0 = 'Berryl' [Type: String (0)], @p1 = 'Hesh' [Type: String (0)], @p2 = 32768 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p3 = 65536 [Type: Int32 (0)]
NHibernate: SELECT employee_.EmployeeNumberValue as Employee2_1_ FROM Employees employee_ WHERE employee_.EmployeeId=@p0;@p0 = 65536 [Type: Int32 (0)]
NHibernate: INSERT INTO Employees (FirstName, LastName, DepartmentId, EmployeeId) 
        VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);@p0 = 'Berryl' [Type: String (0)], @p1 = 'Hesh' [Type: String (0)], @p2 = 32768 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p3 = 65537 [Type: Int32 (0)]
NHibernate: SELECT employee_.EmployeeNumberValue as Employee2_1_ FROM Employees employee_ WHERE employee_.EmployeeId=@p0;@p0 = 65537 [Type: Int32 (0)]
Test failed: 
   Expected: 1
   But was:  0
```

OBJECT MODEL

```
public class Employee : Entity, IResource
{
    public virtual long EmployeeNumberValue { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

MAPPING:

```
  <class name="Employee" table="Employees">

<id name="Id" unsaved-value="0">
  <column name="EmployeeId" />
  <generator class="hilo" />
</id>

<property name="EmployeeNumberValue" generated="insert" insert="false" update="false" >
  <column name="EmployeeNumberValue" sql-type="int IDENTITY(1,1)" index="IDX_EmployeeNumber"  />      
</property>

...
```

```
create table Employees (
    EmployeeId INTEGER not null,
   EmployeeNumberValue int IDENTITY(1,1),
   FirstName TEXT not null,
   LastName TEXT not null,
   DepartmentId INTEGER,
   primary key (EmployeeId)
)
```

I suspect the way I am marking the column as IDENTITY is also suspect. I tried using database-object as below, but got a usage error in doing so

```
  <database-object>
    <create>
      ALTER TABLE Employee DROP COLUMN EmployeeNumberValue
      ALTER TABLE Employee ADD EmployeeNumberValue INT IDENTITY
    </create>
    <drop>
      ALTER TABLE Employee DROP COLUMN EmployeeNumberValue
    </drop>
  </database-object>

SQLiteException : SQLite error  "DROP": syntax error
```

Comment: Is your property really named "Value" and not "EmployeeNumber"? This should work: `<property name="Value" column="EmployeeNumber" generated="insert"/>`. Did you make that column `identity`?

Comment: @Diego the last bit was an issue, so I changed the mapping to make the column identity as shown in the revised mapping. I may still be confused on the properties, since the value is not being assigned. Employee has a property called EmployeeNumber, which is itself a value object (component) that has a property called Value.

Comment: @Diego - making the column identity is also a bit tricky. do you have a different way that you like to use?

Comment: @Berryl: Why the component and the ValueObject inheritance, and all that jazz? Just use a simple `public virtual long EmployeeNumber { get; set; }` in Employee with the mapping I gave you and it will work.

Comment: @Diego: having it as an object makes it easy to format the display value. I have a more complicated but similar situation with ProjectNumbers that should be auto-incremented by a prefix, point being that I'd like to be able to solve the situation with components. Can you think of anything else I can try?

Comment: @Berryl: formatting a value for display is not a responsibility of the domain. And you can always use an unmapped property to do the formatting anyway.

Comment: @Diego. Respectfully, you really don't think you know someone else's domain just from reading a question about how to do something using a various NHib technique, do you?

Comment: @Diego. The answer to [this posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870130/nhibernate-generate-a-business-key) is closer to what I'm looking for - make the generation of business sequences an app feature handled by the domain, and not the data access layer. Do you think you could scratch out how a listener *might* do the job?

Comment: @Berryl: implement and register `IPreInsertEventListener`, use a query to retrieve the max value, the usual hack seen in audit listeners to modify the property value... and watch your app scalability die.

Comment: @Diego: fair enough & thanks for your help so far. I've edited this question to focus simple on the generated property technique, and figure out why it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a design perpective I wouldn't rely on NHibernate in this case. What I mean is, that in your domain model, you want an employee to get a new employee card number.

In this case I would only allow an employee to be instantiated if there is a card number.

```
public class EmployeeCardNumber
{
    private string id = String.Empty;
    internal EmployeeCardNumber(string id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}


public class Employee
{
    private EmployeeCardNumber employeeCardNumber;

    public EmployeeCardNumber CardNumber { ... }

    public Employee(EmployeeCardNumber employeeCardNumber)
    {
        this.employeeCardNumber = employeeCardNumber;
    }
}
```

So now you have to think about how to generate a unique EmployeeCardNumber.

```
public class EmployeeCardNumberFactory
{
    public EmployeeCardNumber CreateNew()
    {
        // in this example the card number will be a guid.
        // but you could also implement a "EmployeeCardNumberGenerator" class which will do crazy database stuff
        return new EmployeeCardNumber(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you would later do:

```
EmployeeCardNumber cardNumber = employeeCardNumberFactory.CreateNew();
Employee employee = new Employee(cardNumber, name, etc...);
```

**Addition:**
To generate a "EmployeeCardNumber" via database, you could just map "EmployeeCardNumber" to an extra table "EmployeeCardNumber" that will serve as your identity generator like:

```
<class name="EmployeeCardNumber" table="EmployeeCardNumber">
    <id name="id" access="field" unsaved-value="0">
      <column name="EmployeeCardNumberId" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
</class>
```

Then in the factory you could do:

```
public class EmployeeCardNumberFactory
{
    private IEmployeeCardNumberRepository repository = new EmployeeCardNumberRepository(); // inject...
    public EmployeeCardNumber CreateNew()
    {     
        EmployeeCardNumber cardNumber = new EmployeeCardNumber();
        repository.Save(cardNumber); // gets you a fresh id
        return cardNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is closer to my preference, as you can see from [this related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236902/domain-model-sequence-number), which seemed to interest exactly nobody. I like the idea of a separate table to generate sequential ids too, although I am still wondering why the documented generated property didn't work here. Have you actually used a pattern like this in a project?

Comment: Yes of course, this is more or less domain driven design. While an artifical id like auto generated database ids are meaningless and are just for technical purposes (joins, referential integrity, only way to create unique identity of an entity), your card number serves a specific business purpose within your business domain. This is why it should be explictly modelled like that in your domain model. The only downside I see in the pattern above is that there can now be 2 employees having the same card number. To take care of that, EmployeeCardNumber should only be instantiated with an employee.

Comment: Not so sure about that - an add can of course be canceled. Seems like the trick here is more in the save, maybe assigning the number as part of that transaction.

Answer (score 2):

While that's doable, it's better to do it in the DB (using identity or a trigger) and map the property as generated on insert.

Check [5.5. Generated Properties](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-generated)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - my motivation for asking was twofold. 
Firstly, I thought the listener/interceptor approach would avoid the extra SELECT. Secondly, my attempts to use generated do not appear to be working. Please see my UPDATED post comments / mapping

Comment: @Berryl: how would you do it without a select? Even with raw ADO.NET that's not possible unless you assume a lot (and use some nasty locks) or use a query inside the select statement.

Comment: honestly I am not sure; another SO post implied it could be done with an interceptor, but without saying how.

Answer (score 0):

I had same scenario and it works very well in production.

Here is mapping (generated by Fluent NHibernate):

```
<property generated="insert" name="Number" update="false" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <column name="Number" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

In database this column looks like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [DeviceLink] ADD [Number] INT not null IDENTITY (1, 1)
```