# domain model sequence number

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, identity

I have a need to assign the next sequence number for a Project according to a given prefix code. So you wind up with alternate id numbers like PROJ_ABC_001, PROJ_ABC_002, PROJ_XYZ_001, PROJ_XYZ_002, etc.

While this need is quite specific, I would suggest that there is a more general and common case where businesses use alternate ids that are sequential integers in order to identify different Customers, Projects, Orders - whatever.

Of course these aren't primary keys in the database. And while databases are a logical place to maintain and generate a sequence number, only the application knows the specific rules of a given use case.

Have you ever treated a sequence number as a domain object in an application? Can you suggest any design pattern(s) to do so in a multi-user environment?

Cheers,
Berryl

Comment: This is not something anyone can answer because it will depend on specifics of your application.  Can a counter be initialized from a database then incremented to generate new sequences?  Maybe but we do not know how your ids are generated if there are thread safety issues etc.  This is also an algorithm question that is very specific to your problem domain, not a design pattern question.  A design pattern is a generally useful domain agnostic solution to a commonly occurring problem.  I am retagging accordingly.  You may want to reformulate the question, just not enough info here.

Comment: @Sisyphus - I have reformulated to more clearly get my intention of seeing how one or more design patterns might solve the general problem. Let me know if it makes more sense to you now - cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest answer I found here was along the lines of the accepted answer for a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191005/nhibernate-alternate-ids-using-generated-properties).

That posting is much more NHibernate specific than I'd like, so this is a half-hearted answer. Love to see a more technology agnostic (ie, design pattern) type of answer.

Cheers,
Berryl